# How to make nullable column in typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

Here I have an User entity, where image is going to be an optional column (user avatar):

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string

    @Column({ unique: true })
    username: string

    @Column()
    name: string

    @Column()
    surname: string

    @Column()
    password: string

    @Column({ default: false })
    isVerified: boolean

    @OneToOne(() => Token, token => token.user)
    token: Token

    @Column({
        type: 'enum',
        enum: UserRole,
        default: UserRole.USER
    })
    role: UserRole

    @OneToOne(() => Image, image => image.user, { nullable: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    image: ???
}
```

I'm a bit confused about image column type.

Does image column type has to be `Image | null` or just `Image` because of { nullable: true } option?

p.s. `Image` is another entity class

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specified that the `OneToOne` relationship is `nullable` (with the `{ nullable: true }` setting), the `image` column can contain `null` values.

In this case, you **can** use the `Image | null` type:

```
@OneToOne(() => Image, image => image.user, { nullable: true })
@JoinColumn()
image: Image | null
```

**That doesn't mean that you have to use the above type.**

Let me give an example where you don't have to.

In your TypeScript code, let's assume that for new rows, `image` field can never be `null`. But you have old rows in your database where `image` is already `null`. So to prevent any new rows from having null Image, you use the below code:

```
@OneToOne(() => Image, image => image.user, { nullable: true })
@JoinColumn()
image: Image
```

Hope that clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

You can define only Image type for that field - and when you want to create your entity later on in the codebase you can instantiate it in the following manner:

```js
this.userRepo.create({
   ... // object fields and types will be inferred from TypeOrm entity class, and you can omit the 'image' field
})
```